# How can one print values of nested hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
$dict{'one'}=1;
print %dict;
```

This will print

> one1

to the terminal. But what if my code has a <s>dictionary</s> hash in a <s>dictionary</s> hash like this:

```
my %dict;
$dict{'1'}{'1'}=2;

print %dict;
```

This gives the output:

```
1HASH(0xb1db78)
```

Even when I change the last line to

```
print $dict{'1'};
```

The output is:

> HASH(0x13ccb78)

How can I get the contents of the <s>dictionary</s> hash instead of the reference location?

Comment: Using your first line gives me syntax error at Untitled.pl line 6, near "%dict["

Comment: @chimpsarehungry I'm sorry. Corrected it.

Comment: even with the curly brackets I still get the error. new to perl too.

Comment: @chimpsarehungry Sorry! Finally corrected it!

Comment: It is worth pointing out that they are called *hashes* in Perl. Not trying to be pedantic but you are more likely to find help in documentation with the correct name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%dict['one']=1;`  << this is wrong

it should be `$dict{'one'}=1;`

You should have something like below. **Warning**: this is untested code, but you get the point what I am trying to say:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %dict;
$dict{'1'}{'1'}=2;
$dict{'2'}{'2'}=3;

#print Dumper(\%dict);

foreach my $keys ( keys %dict )
{
    print "$keys : ";
    foreach my $keys2 ( keys %{ $dict{keys} } )
    {
        print "$keys2 = $dict{keys}{$keys2} \n" ;
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah. It should be $dict{'one'}..
And yeah I get it. I'll try what you said

Answer (score 8):

If you want the whole structure, use the core [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
$hash{1}{1} = 2;

print Dumper( \%hash );
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   '1' => 2
                 }
        };
```

If you want to work with nested structures in Perl (beyond anything trivial) you'll need to learn about *references*. If you're familiar with pointers then you're halfway there.

The best resources are in the official docs:

- [Perl reference tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [Perl arrays of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)
- [Perl data structures cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: You meant to say that working with nested datastructures in perl is not trivial or IF i wanted to do something that isn't trivial?

Anyway, I don't just want to see the output, I want to access all the levels of the nested structure. Dumper just gives the contents right?

Comment: Correct, Dumper does what its name says. it Dumps the whole thing. If you have to access individual values, then learn about perl reference. the links given by friedo are good point to start with.

Comment: On recent perl (5.14) Data::Printer is better.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solutions. you can walk through `hash` or `array` or `hash + array`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

%foo = (
    flintstones => { 
        husband => "fred", 
        pal => "barney", 
    }, 
    jetsons => { 
        husband => [ 
            11, 
            { 
                aa => 100, 
                bb => [ 200, 201, 202 ], 
                cc => 300 
            }, 
            33 
        ], 
        wife => "jane", 
        "his boy" => "elroy",
    }, 
    simpsons => { 
        husband => "homer", 
        wife => "marge", 
        kid => "bart", 
    },
);

sub walk_hash {
    my ($hash, $name) = @_;
    while (my ($key, $value) = each (%{$hash}))
    {
        if (ref $value eq 'HASH') {
            walk_hash($value, $name . "{" . $key . "}");
        } elsif (ref $value eq 'ARRAY') {
            walk_array($value, $name . "{" . $key . "}");
        } else {
            print $name . "{" . $key . "} = $value\n";
        }
    }
}

sub walk_array {
    my ($array, $name) = @_;
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#{$array}; $i++)
    {
        if (ref $$array[$i] eq 'HASH') {
            walk_hash($$array[$i], $name . "[" . $i . "]");
        } elsif (ref $$array[$i] eq 'ARRAY') {
            walk_array($$array[$i], $name . "[" . $i . "]");
        } else {
            print $name . "[" . $i . "] = $$array[$i]\n";
        }
    }
}


walk_hash(\%foo, '%foo');
```

Outputs:

```
bash$ ./test.pl 
%foo{flintstones}{pal} = barney
%foo{flintstones}{husband} = fred
%foo{jetsons}{his boy} = elroy
%foo{jetsons}{wife} = jane
%foo{jetsons}{husband}[0] = 11
%foo{jetsons}{husband}[1]{aa} = 100
%foo{jetsons}{husband}[1]{bb}[0] = 200
%foo{jetsons}{husband}[1]{bb}[1] = 201
%foo{jetsons}{husband}[1]{bb}[2] = 202
%foo{jetsons}{husband}[1]{cc} = 300
%foo{jetsons}{husband}[2] = 33
%foo{simpsons}{kid} = bart
%foo{simpsons}{husband} = homer
%foo{simpsons}{wife} = marge
```